# How to retrieve all Cookies from REST Template?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, cookies, resttemplate

I am working on a project where I want to send a POST REST call and get the response and in the response, there are few cookies. among those, I want to get **X-Bonita-API-Token** and pass it to the frontend.

I used `String set_cookie = httpHeaders.getFirst(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);` this return only the first cookie but i need the second.

my code

```
final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/bonita/loginservice";
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    HttpEntity<ApiRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<>(apiRequest, headers);
    template.getMessageConverters().add(getMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    HttpEntity<String> response = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity,String.class);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = response.getHeaders();
    String set_cookie = httpHeaders.getFirst(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);
```

Here are the returned cookies.

[image]

can anyone help me to retrieve X-Bonita-API-Token?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22853923/3713193 o you could try creating an interceptor.

Comment: this one might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181175/how-to-get-more-than-one-set-cookie-header-from-response-using-retrofit-okhttpcl